# Creating Versioned Data and Finding Differences between versions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, t-sql

I am looking for a good database design solution for easy compare of my versioned information of data. Please review my scenario below for example (I can not place the actual scenario in our application though - very sorry for that.)

### Sample Data:

```
Assembly
-----------
AssemblyId       AssemblyId
--------------------------
1        Assembly1
2        Assembly2


BOM
--------------------------
BOMId   AssemblyId       VersionName        ParentBOMId
-----------------------------------------------------
1           1           V001               NULL
2           1           V002               1
3           1           V003               2
4           1           V004               3
5           1           V005               2
```

[Each time a BOM record is changed, it is inherited from any of the previous version (ParentBOMID) - If it is the first Version for the Assembly the ParentBOMID is Null]

```
BOMDetail
-----------
ID     BOMID       PartName       Qty  
---------------------------------------------------
1     1          Part1             2
2     1          Part2             1
3     1          Part3             2

4     2          Part1             2
5     2          Part2             1
6     2          Part4             2  {Change in PartName here in V002 Base Version V001}

7     3          Part1             2
8     3          Part2             1
9     3          Part4             2
10    3          Part5             9 {Added this part into V003 Base Version V002}

11    4          Part1             2
12    4          Part2             1
13    4          Part4             2
14    4          Part6             9 {this part changed into V004 Base Version V003}

15     5          Part1            2
16     5          Part2            1
17     5          Part9            2  {Change in PartName here in V002 Base Version V002}
```

I need to compare the different BOM Versions with each other. It is easy if need to compare the V001 with V002 OR V004 with V003 because there is ParentBOMId relationship easily available. But in the case of V005 when it is created from V002 AND if someone wants to compare V004 with V001 it is little difficult.

**P.S. I CAN NOT CREATE A MASTER TABLE FOR PARTS I HAVE TO WORK WITH COMPARING THE PART NAMES ONLY.**

Can Anyone suggest me different database design OR easy solution in the case when the Versioning frequencies are VERY VERY HIGH and the parent >> Parent >> parent relationship may go very deep in the hierarchy.

For example I am comparing V001 with V002 output should be

V001   Part1   2    V002    Part1    2

V001   Part2   1    V002    Part2    1

V001   Part3   2    V002    NULL     0

V001   NULL    0    V002    Part4    2

I should be able to compare any Versions with each other and find difference as above.

Comment: You need to tell us what your use cases are.  This is currently far to vague a question to give an answer to.  For example; describe in detail the required output of the different kinds of queries you would need to run.

Comment: I want to compare the BOM versions for changes. For Example Say I am comparing V002 with V001 then output should be as updated into the description above.

Comment: I assume `BomID = 2` is a typo on the last three rows of `BomDetail` *(and that it should be `5`)*?  Also, I assume that `BomID` is unique in the `Bom` table *(and so Assembly2 wouldn't also have BomIDs `{1,2,3,etc}`)*?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic approaches I would use for something like that...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM BomDetail WHERE BomID = 1)     AS bom1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM BomDetail WHERE BomID = 2)     AS bom2
    ON bom1.PartName = bom2.PartName

SELECT
  PartName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN BomID = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END)   AS bom1qty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN BomID = 2 THEN qty ELSE 0 END)   AS bom2qty
FROM
  BomDetail
WHERE
  BomID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
  PartName
```

While the second is longer, it also doesn't need to do a join and so can be faster under certain circumstances.

Comment: It is just not a comparison for Qty - you can notice that the V001 and V003 has parts changed.

Comment: @DipakRiswadkar - Both of these tell you exactly that.  If qty starts or ends as 0, then you know that the part was removed or added.